# "Камешек" или "камушек"?

Tags: орфография

Мне кажется, что "камешек" правильнее, но часто в литературе встречаю и "камушек". Как же все-таки вернее?

Answer (score 2):

Отдельные существительные мужского рода употребляются с суффиксами *-ышек, -ушек,   -ешек*, например: *колышек, **воробышек и воробушек**, xлебушек (также хлебушко), **камешек и камушек**, краешек*.
[gramota.ru/spravka](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BA)

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что нельзя ставить в один ряд слова КРАешек, ВОРОБушек, ВОРОБышек, ХЛЕБушек, КОЛышек и КАМЕШек. Так как в слове "камень" с точки зрения морфемного анализа корень 'камень', окончание нулевое. В словах КАМНи, КАМНепад прослеживается выпадение гласного (как заБОР - заБРали), а в слове КАМЕШек - чередование согласных Н - Ш (как СНЕГ - СНЕЖок).